# VBA use cell value in row selection

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a simple macro that copies the last line in an excel sheet and inserts further up the document. At present the macro only copies one line at a time, however I would like to be able to chose how many lines get copied.

My data is split in the middle with blank rows, hence using `A500 End(xlUp)`, and `A2 End(xlDown)`

```
Dim i As Integer

i = Range("F1").Value

Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Copy
Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I added the `Rows("1:3")` to select three rows, but how can I use the number stored in F1 to select the number of rows to copy?

I tried `Rows("1:i")` but im aware it doesn't quite work like that.

Any guidance would be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added the Rows("1:3") to select three rows, but how can I use the number stored in F1 to select the number of rows to copy?

You can use following

```
Dim NumofRows As Integer

NumofRows = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value2
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:" &NumofRows ).EntireRow.Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the variable out of double quotes

```
Rows("1:" & i)
```